# opencart 1.5 how to add module in a header

Tags: php, opencart

Please some one tell me how can I position modules like slider or banner in header or how can we define additional regions for the modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I am working on it.

Firstly, you should add a new position in the admin page.
Which means you should change three files and add some lines into each.

For example, if you want to add slideshow into header, you should add a new position in

```
$this->data['text_header'] = $this->language->get('text_header'); // in admin/controller/slideshow.php
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$_['text_header']         = 'Header'; // in admin/language/slideshow.php
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'header') { ?> // in admin/view/slideshow.tpl
            <option value="header" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_header; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="header"><?php echo $text_header; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
```

Then a new position for slideshow has been defined. and you can choose it in the admin page.

After that, you should add those codes in catalog/view/header.tpl

```
 <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
    <?php echo $module; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Then, in the catalog/controller/header.php, add some codes like content_top.php does:
     $layout_id = 1;

```
$module_data = array();

$this->load->model('setting/extension');

$extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('module');      

foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $modules = $this->config->get($extension['code'] . '_module');

    if ($modules) {
        foreach ($modules as $module) {
            if ($module['layout_id'] == $layout_id && $module['position'] == 'header' && $module['status']) {
                $module_data[] = array(
                    'code'       => $extension['code'],
                    'setting'    => $module,
                    'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                );              
            }
        }
    }
}

$sort_order = array(); 

foreach ($module_data as $key => $value) {
    $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
}

array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $module_data);

$this->data['modules'] = array();

foreach ($module_data as $module) {
    $module = $this->getChild('module/' . $module['code'], $module['setting']);

    if ($module) {
        $this->data['modules'][] = $module;
    }
}


if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/common/header.tpl';
}

$this->render();
```

Then all done.

The only problem for this code is the slideshow cannot display as a slideshow but a static picture or pictures.

Wish you could solve it out and reply to me.
My question post:
[Opencart developement: change slideshow's position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966066/opencart-developement-change-slideshows-position)

Comment: dont forget to add javascript line like this one..  html += '      <option value="header"><?php echo $text_header; ?></option>';

Comment: Can you please tell me in which file which code should go? I mean first code (admin page). I am trying to add position to my site.

Comment: The problem with slideshow in header is that the header is not including the proper JS nor CSS. It is enough to open the catalog/controller/module/slideshow.php file and copy the line adding a JS resource to the catalog/controller/common/header.php. Therefore I added all the JS and/or CSS resources from any modules into my header and removed them from that modules (so they are not included twice).

Answer (score 2):

do what Huawei Chen wrote and then add these to header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/slideshow.css" media="screen" />
```

and slider will be working

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working. Though a CSS styles are taken in count (there is just empty space where a slider should be) but still a JS error: `$("#slideshow0").nivoSlider is not a function 
$('#slideshow0').nivoSlider();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn from controller/common/column_right.php

Check module position (line 50), you can adapt it to "header":

```
$module['position'] == 'column_right'
```

Set the output (line 69), you can adapt it to something like "header_mod" :

```
$this->data['modules']
```

You need to modificate module at admin to show additional module position.
There is no "*header*" module position options at admin page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an extension that places 2 positions in header and footer. It create the same hooks, like `column_left` and `content_top`, etc.

it works with VQmod for [opencart 1.5x](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6916)

Answer (score 0):

I think this extension will make your life super simple. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&token=extension_id=14467

You can add unlimited number of positions to your header, add columns and change there width all through admin

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This guide helped me:

http://www.mywork.com.au/blog/create-new-module-layout-position-opencart-1-5/

I was using 1.5.6.1 Opencart version.

Comment: Please include content from the link as well in case the link goes bad.  That will make a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read all of your answer. Forget all things. 
   It's very easy to call any module into header section.

Open your `catalog/controller/common/header.php` file

`$this->data['YOUR_MODULE_NAME'] = $this->getChild('module/YOUR_MODULE_NAME');`

Now Open `.tpl` file of header, which is located at 
   `catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/header.tpl`

and echo your desire module whenever you want, like as:
`<?php echo $YOUR_MODULE_NAME;?>`

That's it. you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that your new position is a new child.

```
file: catalog/controller/common/header.php

$this->children = array(
'module/language',
'module/currency',
'module/cart'
);
```

add your new position, like this:

```
$this->children = array(
'common/content_new',
'module/language',
'module/currency',
'module/cart'
);
```

now you can echo your new position in your header.tpl