# Opencart header module display only home pge

Tags: position, opencart

Complete all the steps as here [opencart 1.5 how to add module in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421790/opencart-1-5-how-to-add-module-in-a-header).

But the position is displayed in all schemes. How to output a position only on the main page?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand what are you trying to achieve. May you please explain more? :)

Comment: I created a new position for the slide show in the header template. As described in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421790/opencart-1-5-how-to-add-module-in-a-header. If you activate the slider position that goes on all pages. I need to display only on the main page.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the code from the above tutorial with:

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['route']) || $this->request->get['route'] == 'common/home') {

   //code here

}
```